# SQL - Performing action per record optimal way

Tags: sql, sql-server, geolocation, spatial-query

I have 2 tables, one of which contains geometry column with locations of objects and another one with just point coordinates again in geometry format (SQL Server). I need for each point of the second table to find the closest object from the first. I got a query which can do this for a single point:

```
DECLARE @g geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT 
(1 2,)',0); 
SELECT TOP(1) geom.ToString()
FROM [T1].[dbo].[table_shapes] 
WHERE geom.STDistance(@g) IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY geom.STDistance(@g);
```

Now this will give me the record from the table that is closest to that specific point, but I want to find that closest shape for each point from my table with points coordinates instead of hardcoding the point and also I want to put the result - point - associated shape in a new table. 
I am thinking about some sort of function which will iterate over each record and perform the query above but this may not be the best way as it will be slow... 
Any suggestion how this could be achieved with JOIN maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are looking for this,

DECLARE @g geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT 
(1 2,)',0);

```
select * from mytable tt
CROSS apply(
SELECT TOP(1) geom.ToString()
FROM [T1].[dbo].[table_shapes] 
WHERE geom.STDistance(tt.g) IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY geom.STDistance(tt.g)
)ca
```

why you want to store result in new table ?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, I currently don't have any spatial DB setup. So this is not tested.

```
SELECT s.geom.ToString(), g.geom.ToString()
FROM table_shapes s , (SELECT TOP(1) geom 
                       FROM other_table 
                       WHERE geom geom.STDistance(s.geom) IS NOT NULL
                       ORDER BY geom.STDistance(s.geom)) g
```